# Richtextbox in web application and highlighting the text 

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am a beginner to web application development. I am loading some text to the text box and checking for certain errors like if occurring of space before `.`(dot/full-stop). 
I want to display the line no, column no and cursor position of the errors. Which control is suited for this. How to find the line no,column no and cursor position and how to highlight the error text in the text box.? 
I have heard that through `RichTextBox` it is possible, but richtextbox control is not there in web application toolbox controls list.

Comment: "I want to display the line no, column no and cursor position of the errors." I think you can't find cursor positon via asp.net. You should use a flash or silverlight for it.

Comment: This sounds like a repeat of your other question.  ;)  And like your other question's answerers, I'll tell you that you need to do this with good ol' javascript.

Comment: In that  i was searching for cursor position .. i able to get position of cursor but not line no and column no . Here i want to find the line no and column no of every error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is an overview](http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors) of different rich text editors for the web. My favorite is [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/).